# IE throws expected colon error, works in Chrome? Object array with object literal and function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm writing a function that grabs text from a file and tests the text. It runs smoothly on Chrome, but not on IE? From what I can find online, IE should support everything that I'm working with. When I run it on IE, it throws an "Expected ':'" error at the end of every `test(data)`

Current Code:

```
    function testText(callback)
    {
        const filePaths =
        [
            {
                url: "http://example.com/example.txt",
                test(data)
                {
                    const compareText = data.localeCompare(trigger, "en", {sensitivity: "base"});

                    if (compareText == 0)
                    {
                        globalNotifEnabled = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/UserExceptions.txt",
                test(data)
                {
                    const rawUsers = data;
                    const userExceptions = rawUsers.split(';');

                    if (userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser) > -1)
                    {
                        console.log("User exception is: " + userExceptions[userExceptions.indexOf(currentUser)]);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/test/notification.txt",
                test(data)
                {
                    globalNotification = data;
                    notify(globalNotification);
                    console.log("Global notification displayed.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        ];

        (function getFiles(currentStage)
        {
            $.get(filePaths[currentStage].url, function(data)
            {
                if (filePaths[currentStage].test(data))
                {
                    if (filePaths.length > currentStage + 1) getFiles(currentStage + 1)
                        else callback(null, "Success!")
                }
                else callback(Error(`Stage ${currentStage}'s test failed.`, null))  
            }, 'text')
            .fail(function()
            {
                console.log("Global notifications failed at stage: " + currentStage);
            });
        })(0);
    }
```

Is there a reason that Chrome allows me to access `test(data)` but IE requires me to have something like `blah: function test(data)`? I tried modifying the objects so that it looks like:

```
                url: "http://example.com/example.txt",
                setTest: function(test(data))
                {
                    const compareText = data.localeCompare(trigger, "en", {sensitivity: "base"});

                    if (compareText == 0)
                    {
                        globalNotifEnabled = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

...and calling it in the `getFiles` function like:

```
if (filePaths[currentStage].setTest)
...
```

It doesn't throw errors in IE, but it isn't actually using the function like I need it to in the `getFiles` portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [*method syntax*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-MethodDefinition):

```
{
    url: "http://example.com/example.txt",
    test(data) // <==== here
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That was added in ES2015. IE11 doesn't support it (no version of IE does), but modern browsers do. (I don't think IE11 supports any of ES2015 properly, as it was released in 2013 and Microsoft doesn't add features to existing releases of IE. It has `let`, but the semantics are wrong in `for` loops.)

As you've found, the answer is to use a property initializer instead:

```
{
    url: "http://example.com/example.txt",
    test: function(data)
// -----^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or of course, write modern JavaScript and use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to convert the code to ES5 (perhaps with polyfills) for IE.